# C^r extension of a function defined on a bounded connected open set

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\varOmega \subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded connected open set and $r$ a positive integer.

Given $f\in C^r (\overline \varOmega)$ (i.e. $f$ is $C^r$ on $\varOmega$ and it extends continuously, together with all its partial derivatives up to order $r$, to the whole $\overline \varOmega$).

**Question:** *Does it follows, without further assumption on $\varOmega$, that $f$ has a $C^r$ extension to the whole $\mathbb R^n$?*

---

The answer is negative, as pointed out by Willie Wong - see the counterexample in

[Density of polynomials in $C^k(\overline\Omega)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234480/density-of-polynomials-in-ck-overline-omega)

The answer is positive if $\varOmega$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Your question is answered in the negative as part of the question statement [of this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234480/density-of-polynomials-in-ck-overline-omega).

Comment: Are you familiar with Whitney extension theorem? I think it's answer this question  completely.

Comment: Willie Wong, very elegant counterexample, thank you for posting the link.